# Uploading Photos via App to the fanpage which is hosting the App

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I'm trying to figure out how I can let user upload photos out of my app onto my fanpage (the page which is hosting the app) using the PHP-SDK.

Scenario:

1. User Opens APP
2. There is an upload form where the user chooses a photo to upload
3. After uploading the photo should be on the fanpage which is hosting the app
4. It should look like the user went directly to the fanpage and uploaded a photo and there should also be the notification on his stream saying that he uploaded a photo to XXX

(It's only about the graph api, I don't want a guide describing how to create forms or facebook apps etc.)

My Question: Is this even possible? What I tried:

```
    $data = $fb->api($fb->getPageId().'/photos', 'POST',
        array( 'source' => '@' .$img,
               'message' => 'Test'
    ));
```

I called the api with my page ID. But instead of uploading it to my pages photos it is uploading the image to the users gallery.

I also tried to upload it with the access token of the page. But in order to do this I need the 'manage_pages' permission which the most users would not grant for such a simple thing.

I'd appreciate it very much if somebody could give me a lead into the right direction.
Thanks in advance,
Thomas

Comment: _“I also tried to upload it with the access token of the page. But in order to do this I need the 'manage_pages' permission which the most users would not grant for such a simple thing.”_ – I thought it was your own page? Then the only one who has to give manage_pages permission in order to get a page access token is _you_ …

Comment: That's right. If I understand you right, I just add the 'manage_pages' permission to the scope. Authorize the App, grab the pages access token and remove manage_pages from the scope so the users don't need to accept it?

Comment: The *ADMIN* of the page grants the manage pages permissiona and you use the page access token to upload the photos: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/pages/

Comment: I got this one working but now I'm posting as my Fanpage to my Fanpage. What I wanted to do is to post as user to the page

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/#photos says you need manage_pages permission for posting a photo to a page wall this way, so that will only work for admins, I’d say. Maybe it’s possible though if you chose an album to post to first, and then add a photo to it the way described here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/album/#photos For that, you only need publish_stream permission, but not manage_pages. If a user is allowed to post to that album then depends on the page’s setting, I guess.